# What is need to create a zoomi in effect on a carousel used as a page header

Tags: css, html

I have a website with a header carousel with some images. But I would like to get the effect I see on www.oracle.com. Where the images sort of zoom in and then slide out. I know how to do the carsouel with sliding images but I try server css javascript method and none give the effect as the website.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the slide that exits travels a relatively short distance to the left, then fades out. Meanwhile, the new slide has the text and background both doing a scale transformation independently of each other. So you can animate from something like scale(1.1) to scale(1) for the zoom effect.